# problem in a variant of copy command using mmap()

Tags: c, shared-memory, mmap

I have a program which is another variant of copy program in linux(Actually I'm on Mac OSX).
In order to support copying large files, I wrote something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#define BUFFSIZE 65535
#define PAGESIZE 4096
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char *source, *destination;
  int src_fd, dst_fd;
  unsigned long long bytes_read;
  int bytes = BUFFSIZE;
  struct timeval start, end;
  int overall_time = 0;
  unsigned long long offset = 0;
  struct stat statbuf;
  if(argc < 3){
    printf("copy <source> <destination>\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
source = argv[1];
  destination = argv[2];

  src_fd = open(source, O_RDONLY, 0777);
  if(src_fd < 0){
    perror("src_fd");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  //bytes_read = lseek(src_fd, 0, SEEK_END);
  fstat(src_fd, &statbuf);
  bytes_read = statbuf.st_size;
  dst_fd = open(destination, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777);
  if(dst_fd < 0){
    perror("dst_fd");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  lseek(dst_fd, bytes_read -1, SEEK_SET);
  write(dst_fd, "", 1);

  gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
  while(bytes_read > 0){
    if(bytes_read < BUFFSIZE){
      bytes = bytes_read;
      bytes_read = 0;
    }
    else{
      bytes_read -= bytes;
    }
    void *src_map = mmap(NULL, bytes, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, src_fd, (off_t)offset);
    if(src_map == (void*) MAP_FAILED){
      perror("src_map");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    void *dst_map = mmap(NULL, bytes, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, dst_fd, (off_t)offset);
    if(dst_map == (void*) MAP_FAILED){
      perror("dst_map");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memcpy(dst_map, src_map, bytes);

    int src_unmp = munmap(src_map, bytes);
    if(src_unmp == -1){
      perror("src_unmap");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int dst_unmp = munmap(dst_map, bytes);
    if(dst_unmp == -1){
      perror("dst_unmap");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    offset += 4096;
    bytes_read -= bytes;
  }
  gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
  printf("overall = %d\n", (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec));
  close(src_fd);
  close(dst_fd);
  return 0;
}
```

The goal is to measure the amount of time elapsed to copy a large file with the use of mmap().

The above code is not working for transferring 1GB file.

Any hint for that?

Thank you

Comment: You haven't shown us the part of the code where you set `offset`.  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: offset is set to 0 below the "int main(int argc, char **argv){" 
@NateEldredge

Comment: Those lines aren't in what you posted.

Comment: "In order to support copying large files," --> the types of variables are needed.  Post an [mcve]

Comment: @NateEldredge Added sir

Comment: With all warnings enables, many warnings should show how code is playing loose with integer types.  Without careful type considerations, code will fail large files.  BTW, posted code still does not compile.  For starters, many missing includes.

Comment: That's the entire code sir.  I just did not added preprocessors.

Comment: got it @chux-ReinstateMonica. Just added minimal reproducible code.

Comment: Is the problem because of offset type ?

Comment: It's not the type that's the problem, it's the value.  The offset passed to `mmap` has to be a multiple of the page size.

Comment: Note: `printf("overall = %d\n", (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec));` led to "warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'suseconds_t' {aka 'long int'} [-Wformat=]"

Comment: What is the use of `lseek(dst_fd, bytes_read -1, SEEK_SET);
  write(dst_fd, "", 1);`?  Looks like a problem if `bytes_read == 0`.

Comment: Actually it is not necessary. The program works without two lines @chux-ReinstateMonica

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The problem is in offset value. The offset value should be a multiple of page size.

Comment: OK, so apparently `1024` is not  a multiple of page size.  What code did you use to determine the page size?

Comment: Actually I used Macro to define 4096. But before, I checked the page size using " getconf PAGE_SIZE".

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, The above code is not working for 1GB files. Any hint for changing it ?

Comment: 1) "The above code is not working for 1GB files." is unclear.  I thought your post was failing because the posted code was not working for all sorts of sizes and "`offset` value should be a multiple of page size." fixed it?  2) Be fair about asking [Qs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045130/problem-in-a-variant-of-copy-command-using-mmap/61046189?noredirect=1#comment108001379_61046189) without answering prior [Qs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045130/problem-in-a-variant-of-copy-command-using-mmap/61046189?noredirect=1#comment107999816_61045130).

Comment: I changed the code in the question. I changed the offset value to a multiple of page  size and it works for 36MB file. but it didn't work for 1GB of file. I mean, for example a 1.6GB movie is copied and the program finishes without any error, but when I play the movie, the player cannot play it smoothly @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: "I changed the code in the question" --> better to revert question back as it already has an answer to the original question. Once answers arrive, changing the question makes for a moving target - not appealing to answer as it can go on and on.  I have already provided [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045130/problem-in-a-variant-of-copy-command-using-mmap/61046189?noredirect=1#comment107996596_61045130) (ignored) and a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045130/problem-in-a-variant-of-copy-command-using-mmap/61046189?noredirect=1#comment107999816_61045130) (ignored).